# date picker format not display correct date mvc 5

Tags: jquery, plugins, asp.net-mvc-5, datepicker

I have a problem with my datepicker plugin, when I click on a calendar date,
my date is displayed like this: 26/Aug/2019 and if it is not like that i have this error "The StartDate field must be a date.". I do not want to have the month in letters, I want to display the month in number as 26/08/2019, and I have another problem when the user was on cell phone or with apple, he must write the date like this 26-Aug-2019

This is my html code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, @Resource.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-8" })
      <div class="input-group col-md-5">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
      </div>
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
```

This is my script:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
         $('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({
             dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             yearRange: "-10:+20"
         });

     });
```

and i use this plugin: jQuery.Ui.Widgets.Datepicker

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `dateFormat` property to:

```
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
```

You can see all possible formats by checking the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate).

Comment: This part works to display it, but now it still tells me the same error since I still have to write the month in letters, by the way thank you for taking the time to answer me

Comment: @Frankthetank Change your input from `[type="datetime"]` to `[type="text"]` - datetime has been dropped from html specification https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/336

Comment: I do not see anymore my calendar if i have [type="text"]